# Rename large number of columns in dataframe based upon column name condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have flattened a XLM file into dataframe, in which one of the attributes was a list containing more than 50 values, the resulting dataframe created columns for the list named from 1 to 50
Final dataframe has columns as  A , B , C , D , 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7......50 ,
I want to rename it as
A , B , C , D , Role0,Role1,Role2,Role3,Role4,......Role50, based upon some logic

I could rename the numbered columns as below, however based upon the contents in the list this column count could vary, hence wanted to check how i can based upon some condition change the column names

```py
df.rename(columns={0:'Role0', 1:'Role1', 2:'Role2', ......}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: `df.set_axis([*'ABCD']+[f'Role{i}' for i in range(50)] , axis=1)`

Comment: Or `df.columns[:4].tolist()+("Role"+df.columns[4:].astype(str)).tolist()` if you don't want to specify the range.

Comment: this works , however is there a way to dynamically rename without knowing the location where columns 0,1,2 start , reason am saying this is because the use case which am trying to solve involves flattening an XML which have lists , and these lists could vary could start any location , hence don't want to hardcode

Answer (score 0):

Well, there might be a better solution, but you can do this:
First, declare you dictionnary :

```
my_dict = {0: 'Role0'}
```

Then :  (**f-string** will work for Python 3+)

```
for i in range(1, 51):
    my_dict[i] = f'Role{i}'
```

Then finally do what you did:

```
df.rename(columns=my_dict, inplace=True)
```